# Code for splitter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a treeview and a gridview in my page.My application is windows application in vb.I want to use splitter to move treeview and a gridview.Can anyone help to give the splitter code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the example provided at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx

and you can implement your solution.